# Need help to convert str date to datetime64 pandas python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Is there a way to convert this type (**String**) of date format below:

`Wed Feb 24 18:04:49 SGT 2021`

To datetime64 ns

`2021-02-24`

I tried using code below using pandas and it does not work

```
    data = {'UpdateTime': [
    'Thu May 28 01:24:38 SGT 2020',
    'Wed Feb 24 18:04:49 SGT 2021',
    'Mon Mar 01 20:34:49 SGT 2021',
    'Fri Sep 18 21:29:35 SGT 2020',
    'Tue Feb 09 14:21:56 SGT 2021',
    'Thu Jan 01 07:30:00 SGT 1970',
    ]}

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    df['UpdateTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['UpdateTime'].str.split(' ',1).str[0])
```

and got error

```
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-04 00:00:00
```

I'm pretty sure this is regex issue and I'm not familiar with it. Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think regex here is not necessary, you can specify `format` in `to_datetime`:

```
df['UpdateTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['UpdateTime'], format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S SGT %Y')
print (df)
           UpdateTime
0 2020-05-28 01:24:38
1 2021-02-24 18:04:49
2 2021-03-01 20:34:49
3 2020-09-18 21:29:35
4 2021-02-09 14:21:56
5 1970-01-01 07:30:00
```